# Google Chrome не отображает div-блоки

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Всем привет.

Хром не хочет показывать блоки с фоновыми изображениями. Притом Microsoft Edge их показывает как положено.

HTML + CSS:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Neucha;
    src: url(/static/fonts/Neucha.ttf)
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Pattaya;
    src: url(/static/fonts/Pattaya-Regular.ttf)
}


html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background: #643000;
    font-family: Neucha;
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #F0C975;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.header p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    margin: 20px auto;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.menu {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    background: #643000;
    border-bottom: #F0C975;
}

.menu a {
    font-family: Neucha;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
    color: #F0C975;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
}

.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.picture {
    max-height: 320px;
    background-color: #643000;
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 300px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.image {
    width: 480px;
    height: 320px;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.btest {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Мои фотографии</title>
    <link href="/static/content/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p>Simple Photosite</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Домой</a></li>
                <li><a href="/upload">Загрузить фото</a></li>
                <li><a href="/albums">Альбомы</a></li>
                <li><a href="/manage">Управление</a></li>
                <li><a href="/logout">Выход</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="picture">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(../../photo/temp/20170312004957384000.thumbnail.jpg)">
                    Здесь должен быть коммент
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="picture">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(../../photo/temp/20170312005037520000.thumbnail.jpg)">
                    Здесь должен быть коммент
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="picture">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(../../photo/temp/20170312005840708000.thumbnail.jpg)">
                    Здесь должен быть коммент
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

И сервер говорит, что картинки загружены

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2017 20:28:14] "GET /photo/temp/20170312005037520000.thumbnail.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 14313
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2017 20:28:14] "GET /photo/temp/20170312004957384000.thumbnail.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 32355
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2017 20:28:14] "GET /photo/temp/20170312005840708000.thumbnail.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 55539
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что там в консоли пишет?

Comment: Может AdBlock блокирует их?

Comment: Только Favicon не найден.AdBlock выключен. Более того заключил эти картинки в `<IMG>` и все равно их нет на странице, однако, в хранилище, на вкладке "sources" в консольке эти картинки есть и отображаются

Comment: У меня тоже в Chrome не показывает, причем даже "Здесь должен быть коммент" не показывает - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MpmRBr

Comment: Уберите у .gallery     /* flex: 1 1 0; */ из-за него все пропадает

Comment: Спасибо. Сработало. Эта страничка создавалась как раз для изучения флексов :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите у `.gallery {... flex: 1 1 0; ... }` из-за него все пропадает или замените на `flex: 1 1 auto;`

3-ий параметр принимает значения: [flex-basis](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp):`NN% | NNpx | auto`

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: Neucha;
    src: url(/static/fonts/Neucha.ttf)
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Pattaya;
    src: url(/static/fonts/Pattaya-Regular.ttf)
}


html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    width: auto;
    height: 100px;
    background: #643000;
    font-family: Neucha;
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: #F0C975;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.header p {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    margin: 20px auto;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.menu {
    flex: 1 1 0;
}

.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    background: #643000;
    border-bottom: #F0C975;
}

.menu a {
    font-family: Neucha;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;    
    color: #F0C975;
    text-decoration: none;
}

img {
}

.gallery {
    display: flex;
     flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.picture {
    max-height: 320px;
    background-color: #643000;
    margin: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 300px;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    
}

.image {
    width: 480px;
    height: 320px;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

.btest {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Мои фотографии</title>
    <link href="/static/content/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        <p>Simple Photosite</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Домой</a></li>
                <li><a href="/upload">Загрузить фото</a></li>
                <li><a href="/albums">Альбомы</a></li>
                <li><a href="/manage">Управление</a></li>
                <li><a href="/logout">Выход</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="gallery">
            <div class="picture">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://federalsport.ru/media/k2/items/cache/dc9e231f652301f80ea8e901bd9ec18a_L.jpg)">
                    Здесь должен быть коммент
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="picture">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://federalsport.ru/media/k2/items/cache/dc9e231f652301f80ea8e901bd9ec18a_L.jpg)">
                    Здесь должен быть коммент
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="picture">
                <div class="image" style="background-image: url(http://federalsport.ru/media/k2/items/cache/dc9e231f652301f80ea8e901bd9ec18a_L.jpg)">
                    Здесь должен быть коммент
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```